# GenericDTO and JSF

Tags: jsf, dto

I am currently reading Adam Bien´s book "Java EE Patterns: Rethinking Best Practices".
In chapter "Transfer Object and Data Transfer Object" on page 273 he introduces a generic DTO. 
See also: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/no_duplication_no_decoupling_the

A genericDTO does not follow the bean conventions. 
I was wondering how to use generic DTO together with JSF. 
JSF if not dynamically used (build components on the flight) makes use of java-beans to bind values to UI-Components (for example #{beanA.beanB.myValue}).
A genric DTO does not provide individual getters for attributes or relations.
Instead i would have to call getters with a string parameter.
So accessing it via #{beanA.beanB.myValue} is not possible in JSF (1.2).

Is it possbile to use the genric DTO pattern together with JSF?

Regards,

Max

Comment: Just use `#{beanA.beanB.attributes.myValue}`?

Comment: If I would expose the map attributes<String, Attribute> using a getter that works. Sorry I didn´t see it...

Comment: @BalusC The result would be a EL like this for value binding in JSF: #{beanA.beanB.attributes.myAttribute.value} and if I want to set a specific value I would have to create a Setter for the genric Type T of the Attribute interface. Would you prefer a specific DTO oder a genric DTO solution?  In my opinion it is very ugly to read in the jsf xhtml definition an you loose code completion in IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I have not read the entirety of Adam's article, so can not comment on when using this pattern is appropriate. However, EL-expressions do support maps with the `.` or `[]` operators, i.e. if you have:

```
@Named
public class MyBean {
    private Map<String, Object> attributes;

    public Map<String, Object> getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }
}
```

you can use

```
#{myBean.attributes.name}
```

or

```
#{myBean.attributes['name']}
```

to get or set the map entry with key "name".